# How can I stop TinyMCE adding "<br data-mce-bogus=1">

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I am using a rich text area that TinyMCE offers in a self hosted solution.
When I add a bulleted list and add a new item, the text `<br data-mce-bogus="1">` is added to the mark up. I don't want this.

[image]

and the markup on the page...

[image]

Why is TinyMCE adding this and can anyone help with how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TinyMCE APIs to extract the content (`getContent()`) you should not see that `<br data-mce-bogus="1">`.

That `<br>` is an internal marker (TinyMCE uses a variety of them) and none of the internal markers are returned when using TinyMCE's APIs to extract the content.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "extract the content". I'm creating a bullet list with the bullet list button, and the typing something so that i have a bulleted list. 
Everytime I press return to create a new list item, a list item is created with the markup as above. I don't know what I would be doing outside of normal usage here.

Further if I set the cursor beside the empty bullet list, I can't seem to delete the bullet point by pressing the backspace key. However, if I position the cursor at the last line of the previous bullet list item and press the `DELETE` key, it deletes.

Answer (score -1):

Adding 'lists' to the configuration of the TinyMCE text area was enough to solve all my woes.

For example,

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.mceEditor",
    content_css: 'style.css',
    plugins: 'lists',
```